# How to concatenate data properties in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, concatenation

Basically I have a couple data strings in my data object, what I want, is to concatenate one the the strings, into the other.  I want the user to be able to see the date of the last server update.

```
            lastUpdate: "10/30/3033",
            message: 'Servers last updated: ',
```

So ideally it would display "message + lastUpdate"
Also I cant just string it together in HTMl because I need to be able to swap out the message for other strings.  I could seperate out my messages in html, but i want to learn if there is a more dynamic way to do this.

Putting it into the context of my code we have the following parent componenet:

```
<template>
  <div id="main-container" class="col-sm-12">
    <h1>Server Display</h1>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  <div id="mini-container" class="col-sm-3" v-for="(server, index) in servers">
    <h3>({{index+1}}): {{server}}</h3>
    <mi-single-server  :servers="servers"
                       @serversReset="message = $event"></mi-single-server>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  import SingleServer from './SingleServer.vue';

  export default{
    data: function(){
        return{
            lastUpdate: "10/30/3033",
            servers: ['Blue', 'Aphex', 'Maxamillion', 'T180', 'T190', 'NW0'],
            message: 'Servers last updated: '
        };
      },
     components: {
        'mi-single-server': SingleServer
     }
   }
 </script>
```

What I would love to be able to do is to add something like the following to my data table

```
   message: 'Servers last updated: ' + this.lastUpdate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a computed property so it would automatically adjust when `lastUpdate` changes:

```
export default{
    data: function(){
        return{
            lastUpdate: "10/30/3033",
            servers: ['Blue', 'Aphex', 'Maxamillion', 'T180', 'T190', 'NW0']
        };
    },
    components: {
        'mi-single-server': SingleServer
    },
    computed: {
        message: function(){
            return 'Servers last updated: ' + this.lastUpdate
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like you would as if it was in `data`, but you would have to change your event to update `lastUpdate` instead of `message`.

Answer (score 1):

You can update `data` property using `created` hook

```
export default{
    data: function(){
        return{
            lastUpdate: "10/30/3033",
            servers: ['Blue', 'Aphex', 'Maxamillion', 'T180', 'T190', 'NW0'],
            message: 'Servers last updated: '
        };
      },
     components: {
        'mi-single-server': SingleServer
     },
     created: function(){
        this.message = 'Servers last updated: ' + this.lastUpdate
     }
   }
```

Or you can also use `mounted` hook instead of `created` hook